# No converter found for return value of type: class org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.DefaultOAuth2AccessToken

Tags: spring-boot, security, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm getting OAuth token but when at the time of return it gives below error.

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.DefaultOAuth2AccessToken
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:233)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:223)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)
```

Below is attached pom.xml file I'm using

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>integration-platform</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>integration-platform</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    
    
    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.platform.integration.IntegrationPlatformApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.68</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Oauth2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
            <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>18.3.0.0</version>     
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
             <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
             <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20090211</version>
</dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth/spring-security-oauth2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.14</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.27.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
   </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                <jvmArguments>-Dorg.apache.xml.dtm.DTMManager=org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault</jvmArguments>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```